# "emmet-butt" - Westcountry dialect

Tags: dialects, british-english, is-it-a-phrase

My grandfather's family were from Somerset in the southwest of England and one of his favourite pieces of Westcountry dialect was '*emmet-butt*', which apparently meant/means a 'mole hill'.

However, I can't seem to find any reference to this term online.
The closest thing that I have found is 'emmet-batch', which apparently is an 'ant hill'  ([Dialect of the West of England](https://archive.org/stream/dialectwestengl00jenngoog/dialectwestengl00jenngoog_djvu.txt))

Is it possible that my grandfather got confused? Or maybe I have made a mistake in my recollection? 
Any Westcountry dialect specialists out there?

Comment: Since an *"emmet"* is an *"ant"* ([see dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emmet?q=emmet)), an *"emmet-butt"* really should be an *"ant-hill"*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Emmet* is an old word for an ant, and *Butt* (or *Butte*) is a hill, in both cases not just in the west country dialect, so you are right to think that an *emmet butt* is an anthill.

In the west country a *batch* is a low hill, there are many place names in Somerset for example which incorporate it.  However, *batchy* is an adjective meaning stupid.

You should also consider that there is more than one west country dialect.  Words are not necessarily the same as you move further west.  I would suspect both are correct in different counties.  Unfortunately I can't be more specific as, although I'm Somerset born and bred, I can't say I remember hearing either used.

Comment: I think I must have recalled it incorrectly. My grandfather probably said ant hill rather than mole hill. Thanks Chenmunka and Peter!

Answer (score 3):

According to the *OED*, *emmet* is ultimately a variant of *ant* and derives from the Old English word *æmete*:

> **Emmet** ... {repr. OE *æmete* wk. fem. (see ANT). The OE *æ* in stressed initial syllables frequently underwent shortening in ME, and was in that case variously represented according to dialects by *ă* or *ě*. Hence the two forms *ămete* and *ěmete* ; the former of which became contracted into *amt*, ANT, while the latter retained its middle vowel and survives as *emmet*.} **1.** A synonym of ANT. Chiefly *dial.*, but often used *poet.* or *arch.* **Horse-emmet**, the Wood Ant (*Formica rufa*). **2.** *attrib.*, as *emmet-swarm*. Also **emmet-batch**, **-but**, **-cast** (*dial*.) = ANT-HILL.

The  earliest occurrence of *emmet* that the *OED* cites is from the circa 850 *Kentish Glossary*, where it appears as *emetan*. The earliest match for *emmet* in an Early English Books Online search is from [*Biblia the Byble, that is, the holy Scrypture of the Olde and New Testament, faithfully translated in to Englyshe*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A10349.0001.001/1:26.6?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=emmet*) (1535) in a familiar proverb of Solomon:

> Go to the **Emmet** (thou slogarde) cōsidre hir wayes, & lerne to be wyse / She hath no gyde, no teacher, no leder: yet in the sommer she prouideth hir meate, & gathereth hir foode together ī ye haruest.

As for *butt* (or *but*), an interesting discussion of this term appears in Ernest Adams, "[On the Names of Ants, Earwigs, and Beetles](https://books.google.com/books?id=FIMNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA95&dq=%22emmet+but%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq4ZriiIzxAhUkG6YKHaZQCJE4FBDoATABegQIBRAC#v=onepage&q=%22emmet%20but%22&f=false)," in *Transactions of the Philological Society* (1858):

> In Somersetshire the ant-hill is called an *emmet-batch*. *Batch* is another form of botch, a boil or swelling, and the ant-hill may be compared to a boil or tumour on the face of the field; compare Dutch *butse*, "*Batch*: a mound; an open space by the road-side; a sand-bank or patch of ground lying near a river" ([Thomas] Wright). Cf. *allern-batch*, a kind of botch or old sore (Exmoor). In the same county the ant-hill is also known as an ***emmet-but***. In the dialects of Somerset and Exmoor a bee-hive is termed a *bee-but*, and Halliwell adds another meaning of the word *but*: " a peculiar kind of conical basket used in the river Parret for catching salmon".—It is apparently the A.S. word *bót* or *bút*, seen in the diminutive *bótle* or *bútle*, a house, and still retained in local names in many parts of the kingdom: Bot-ley, But-leigh, Bat-ly, Bet-ley, and Boot-le, and in the modern English *booth*. '***Emmet-but***' may fairly be translated 'ant-house'.

James Jennings, [*Observations on Some of the Dialect of the West of England, Particularly Somersetshire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xRRJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22But+s+A+conical%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsirL4lozxAhVJpZ4KHUI5CKQQ6AEwAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22But%20s%20A%20conical%22&f=false) (1825) offers further details about *but* in this sense:

> **But.** *s.* A conical and peculiar kind of basket or trap used in large numbers for catching salmon in the river Parret. The term *but*, would seem to be a generic one, the actual meaning of which I do not know : it implies, however, some containing vessel or utensil See BEE-BUT [noted earlier in the glossary in this brief entry: "Bee-but. [or] Bee-lippen. *s.* A bee-hive."]. *But*, applied to beef, always means *buttock*.

As noted by the poster of the original question above, Jennings also has an entry for *emmet-batch*:

> **Emmet-batch,** *s*. An ant-hill.

But Jennings does not mention *emmet-but* as an alternative term for "anthill."

One of the earliest instances in print of *emmet-but* (cited by Adams in his 1858 article) appears in James Halliwell-Phillipps, [*A Dictionary of Archaic and Provincial Words, Obsolete Phrases, Proverbs, and Ancient Customs, from the Fourteenth Century*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ghYtAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA332&dq=%22Emmet-batch%22+%22emmet-but%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirhaaLgYzxAhVCvJ4KHQuVBHYQ6AEwAHoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Emmet-batch%22%20%22emmet-but%22&f=false) (1847):

> EMMET-BATCH. An ant-hill. *Somerset*. Also called an ***emmet-but***.

Even earlier, however, is this mention of *emmet-butt* in the glossary of William Barnes, [*Poems of Rural Life, in the Dorset Dialect, with a Glossary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=00gCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA303&dq=%22emmet-butt%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9pIGy_4vxAhULq5QKHVcEBoYQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22emmet-butt%22&f=false) (1844):

> **Emmet-butt** or Emmet-hill. An ant hill.

Barnes uses the term *emmet buts* in his poem "[The Common A-Took In](https://books.google.com/books?id=00gCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA303&dq=%22emmet-butt%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9pIGy_4vxAhULq5QKHVcEBoYQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=snippet&q=%22emmet%20buts%22&f=false)," printed in that same volume:

> Ees, while the ragged colts did crop / The nibbled grass, I used to hop / The **emmet buts** from top to top / So proud of my spry jumps; / An' thee behine ar at my zide, / Di'st skip so litty an' so wide / 'S thy little frock wo'd let thee stride / Among the vuzzy humps.

Barnes returns to the topic of emmet butts in "[The Waggon A-Stooded](https://books.google.com/books?id=E0NZuj1kT9MC&pg=PA20&dq=%22emmet+butts%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjipu3omozxAhXNop4KHRxbAKkQ6AEwBHoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22emmet%20butts%22&f=false)," in *Hwomely Rhymes: A Second Collection of Poems in the Dorset Dialect* (1859):

> What then. I coulden leäve the beäten track, / To turn the waggon awver on the back / Ov oone o' theäsem **emmet-butts**. / If you be sich a drever, an' do know 't, / You dreve the plow, then ; but you'll awverdrow 't.
>
> ...
>
> Oh! ees, d'ye think I be a nincompoop, / No, no. The lwoad wer built so firm 's a rock, / But two o' theäsem **emmet-butts** would knock / The tightest barrel out o' hoop.

It thus appears that Dorset has as good a claim as Somerset to early published use of *emmet butt*.

Answer (score 1):

I be from Templecombe,I be 76 gwoin on 77, an ant hill was always called an emmit butt. If volk sed ‘ant hill’ they was posh, I knowd somebody once oo always sed that, bugger, I always took me ‘at off to in

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This is a copy of a poem written by Arthur at Tyneham village school in Dorset. The school and village were abandoned in 1932 and used by the NAAFFI.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Please see the [help] and site [tour].  It would help to include the text of the poem, emphasis on the relevant lines.  Screen readers will have difficulty with this image.

Answer (score 0):

Your grandfather does not seem to have been referring to molehills:

[North Somerset dialect](http://www.ycccart.co.uk/index_htm_files/Dialect%20words%20in%20reports-2.pdf) Wantitumps - Mole hills.

[More Somerset Dialect:](https://somersetspeaks.wordpress.com/2017/05/31/want-for-nothing/)

> ‘Want’, for example.  In Somerset, Wiltshire, Devon, Cornwall and Dorset, this word is either the majority term, or is almost exclusively used by the participants.  So, those counties that would be included in the South West.  Other Southern and South-Eastern counties used only ‘mole’, and there was no sign of ‘want’ in there at all.

And Wikipedia from a neighbouring county, [Dorset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Dorset_dialect_words): Wont - Mole, small burrowing mammal of the family Talpidae